# Selecting data from multiple tables with mysql fetch_object

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm really new in web aplications and using relational databases, and I am trying to make a `select` and a `print` from 5 tables at the same time using this method that I saw in a YouTube video, in the first `select` I am selecting a person and storing all of his data in variables including the foreign keys, after that I am selecting data from the other 4 tables using the foreign keys stored in variables from the person and at last I'm printting all data on a table row.

I know the method is functional I have already used it to select from a single table flawlessly but here trying to select form multiple tables doesnt work, maybe I should try with a `JOIN` in the first select and selecto all tables from there. Where I run this php script it returns this error:

> Undefined variable: db in C:\wamp64\www\sicu\paciente.php on line 71" and this " Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\wamp64\www\sicu\paciente.php on line 71

```
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * from `paciente` ORDER BY `ci_p`";
    $result = $db-> query ($sql);

    while ($row = $result ->fetch_object()) {



    $ci_p = $row -> ci_p;
    $primer_nombre =htmlentities ($row -> primer_nombre, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $segundo_nombre = htmlentities ($row -> segundo_nombre, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $primer_apellido = htmlentities ($row ->primer_apellido , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); 
    $segundo_apellido = htmlentities ( $row -> segundo_apellido, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $sexo = htmlentities ( $row -> sexo, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $tipo_p = htmlentities ( $row -> tipo_p, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $tipo_personal = htmlentities ( $row -> tipo_personal, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $especialidad= htmlentities ( $row -> especialidad, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $alergias = htmlentities ( $row -> alergias, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $correo_id_correo = htmlentities ( $row -> correo_id_correo, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $telefono_id_telefono = htmlentities ( $row -> telefono_id_telefono, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $direccion_id_direccion = htmlentities ($row -> direccion_id_direccion , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $fecha_id_fecha = htmlentities ($row -> fecha_id_fecha , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

    $sql1 = "SELECT * from `direccion` where id_direccion = '$direccion_id_direccion')";
    $result1 = $db-> query ($sql1);
    while ($row1 = $result1 ->fetch_object()){
        $estado =htmlentities ($row -> estado, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $ciudad = htmlentities ($row -> ciudad, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $municipio = htmlentities ($row ->municipio , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); 
        $parroquia = htmlentities ( $row -> parroquia, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $sector = htmlentities ( $row -> sector, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $edificio = htmlentities ( $row -> edificio, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $piso= htmlentities ( $row -> piso, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $numero = $row -> numero;
        $punto_ref = htmlentities ( $row -> punto_ref, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $avenida = htmlentities ( $row -> fecha_ingre, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

    }
    $sql2 = "SELECT * from `correo_electronico` where id_correo = '$correo_id_correo')";
    $result2 = $db-> query ($sql2);
    while ($row2 = $result2 ->fetch_object()){
        $direccion_correo =htmlentities ($row -> direccion_correo, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

    }
        $sq3 = "SELECT * from `telefono` where id_telefono = '$telefono_id_telefono')";
    $result3 = $db-> query ($sql3);
    while ($row3 = $result3 ->fetch_object()){
    $numero_telefono = $row -> numero_telefono;

    }
        $sql5 = "SELECT * from `fecja_naci` where id_fecha_naci = '$fecha_id_fecha')";
    $result5 = $db-> query ($sql5);
    while ($row5 = $result5 ->fetch_object()){
    $fecha =htmlentities ($row -> fecha, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

    }
?>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><?php echo $ci_p?></td>
        <td><?php echo " $primer_nombre $segundo_nombre $primer_apellido $segundo_apellido "?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sexo ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tipo_p ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tipo_personal?></td>
        <td><?php echo $especialidad?></td>
        <td><?php echo $alergias ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fecha?></td>
        <td><?php echo $numero_telefono?></td>
        <td><?php echo $direccion_correo?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$estado $ciudad $municipio $parroquia $sector $edificio $piso $numero $punto_ref $avenida"?></td>
    </tr></tbody>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You need a working mysqli connection before you can query, like `$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`

Comment: i had a conect.php file and forgot to include it, then changed that method to an to an inner join _italic_**bold** `include "php/connect.php";
$sql = "SELECT * from paciente inner JOIN direccion ON direccion_id_direccion =id_direccion
inner join telefono on telefono_id_telefono = id_telefono INNER JOIN
correo_electronico on correo_id_correo = id_correo inner JOIN
fecha_naci on fecha_id_fecha = id_fecha_naci ORDER BY `ci_p`";
$result = $db-> query ($sql)`

Answer (score 0):

First, make a file connection.php

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli("Host name","User","DB Password","DB Name");

// ceck connection

if ($db->connect_error) {
   die('Connection failed: '. $connect->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Then add this code :

```
include "connection.php";
```

in your php file.

my advice use the inner join in the mysql

Comment: thanks a lot i totally forgot to first make the data base conection, even so with this method to couldnt select correclty from multiple tables so i did as you said with the join, but i used an inner join and work perfectly and reduce like 30 code lines. thanks a lot